# How to display SId, SName and Location of those salesmen who have total sales amount greater than average sales amount of all the sales made

Tags: sql, database

Question is: Display SId, SName and Location of those salesmen who have total sales amount greater than average sales amount of all the sales made. Amount can be calculated from Price and Discount of Product and Quantity sold. We have to use Independent Subquery.

This is the data structure of question:
Salesman Table
SID SNAME   LOCATION
1   Peter   London
2   Michael Paris
3   John    Mumbai
4   Harry   Chicago
5   Kevin   London
6   Alex    Chicago

Product Table
PRODID  PDESC           PRICE           CATEGORY            DISCOUNT
101 Basketball  10          Sports                  5
102 Shirt           20          Apparel                 10
103 NULL            30          Electronics         15
104 Cricket Bat 20          Sports                  20
105 Trouser         10          Apparel                 5
106 Television  40          ELECTRONICS         20

Sale Table
SALEID  SID SLDATE          AMOUNT
1001    1   01-Jan-14   NULL
1002    5   02-Jan-14   NULL
1003    4   01-Feb-14   NULL
1004    1   01-Mar-14   NULL
1005    2   01-Feb-14   NULL
1006    1   01-Jun-15   NULL

Saledetail Table
SALEID  PRODID  QUANTITY
1001    106 2
1001    103 1
1002    102 5
1002    101 1
1003    104 1
1003    101 1
1004    103 1
1004    104 2
1004    106 1
1005    101 3
1005    106 1
1006    102 6
1006    104 1

Below is the code what I did:

SELECT S.Sid, S.Sname, S.Location
FROM Salesman S
WHERE (
SELECT SUM((P.Price - (P.Price * P.Discount / 100)) * SD.Quantity)
FROM SaleDetail SD
JOIN Sale SA ON SD.Saleid = SA.Saleid
JOIN Product P ON SD.Prodid = P.Prodid
WHERE SA.Sid = S.Sid
) > (
SELECT AVG(TotalSales)
FROM (
SELECT SUM((P.Price - (P.Price * P.Discount / 100)) * SD.Quantity) AS TotalSales
FROM SaleDetail SD
JOIN Sale SA ON SD.Saleid = SA.Saleid
JOIN Product P ON SD.Prodid = P.Prodid
GROUP BY SA.Sid
) AvgSales
);

I am getting this output:
SID SNAME   LOCATION
1   Peter   London

But this is the Expected Result
SID SNAME   LOCATION
1   Peter   London
5   Kevin   London

I have tried lot, but I am not getting expected output. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - please format your data as tables and your SQL as code. At the moment your question is really difficult to read

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the query you provided is close to the correct solution, but there's a small issue in your subquery. You need to make sure that the subquery in the WHERE clause of the main query correctly calculates the total sales amount for each salesman and compares it to the average sales amount. Here's the corrected query:

```
SELECT S.Sid, S.Sname, S.Location FROM Salesman S WHERE (
    SELECT SUM((P.Price - (P.Price * P.Discount / 100)) * SD.Quantity)
    FROM SaleDetail SD
    JOIN Sale SA ON SD.Saleid = SA.Saleid
    JOIN Product P ON SD.Prodid = P.Prodid
    WHERE SA.Sid = S.Sid ) > (
    SELECT AVG(TotalSales)
    FROM (
        SELECT SA.Sid, SUM((P.Price - (P.Price * P.Discount / 100)) * SD.Quantity) AS TotalSales
        FROM SaleDetail SD
        JOIN Sale SA ON SD.Saleid = SA.Saleid
        JOIN Product P ON SD.Prodid = P.Prodid
        GROUP BY SA.Sid
    ) AvgSales );
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still getting this output:                                                               SID SNAME LOCATION 
1 Peter London                                                                                                       
but  this is the Expected Result                                                                              
SID SNAME LOCATION 
1 Peter London 
5 Kevin London

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
SELECT S.SID, S.SNAME, S.LOCATION
FROM Salesman S
JOIN Sale SA ON S.SID = SA.SID
JOIN Saledetail SD ON SA.SALEID = SD.SALEID
JOIN Product P ON SD.PRODID = P.PRODID
GROUP BY S.SID, S.SNAME, S.LOCATION
HAVING AVG((P.PRICE * (1 - P.DISCOUNT/100) * SD.QUANTITY)) > 
(SELECT AVG((P.PRICE * (1 - P.DISCOUNT/100) * SD.QUANTITY)) AS 
AVERAGE_SALE_AMOUNT
FROM Saledetail SD
JOIN Product P ON SD.PRODID = P.PRODID);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).